# How to spawn prefabs within a certain period of time in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject, spawning

I am trying to create a ball hitting game in the baseball format. I create a ball as a prefab. I want to push the ball to the main scene within a certain period of time.

For example; when the first ball is in the scene, the second ball will spawn after 5-6 seconds, then the third, fourth etc. I am the beginner level of Unity and I am not good at C#. I am not sure whether I am using the true functions such as Instantiate. Here is my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {
    public float RotateSpeed = 45; //The ball rotates around its own axis
    public float BallSpeed = 0.2f; 

    public GameObject[] prefab;

    public Rigidbody2D rb2D;

    void Start() {
        rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); //Get component attached to gameobject
        Spawn ();
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        rb2D.MoveRotation(rb2D.rotation + RotateSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime); //The ball rotates around its own axis
        rb2D.AddForce(Vector2.left * BallSpeed);
        InvokeRepeating("Spawn", 2.0f, 2.0f);

    }

    public void Spawn () 
    {
        int prefab_num = Random.Range(0,3);
        Instantiate(prefab[prefab_num]);
    }

}
```

After I apply this script, the result is not what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Add `InvokeRepeating("Spawn", 2.0f, 2.0f);` to the `Start` not the `FixedUpdate`.
`InvokeRepeating` invokes the method `methodName` in time seconds, then repeatedly every `repeatRate` seconds.
You can check the documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html).

Answer (score 3):

## Use [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

```
private IEnumerator SpawnBall() {
    while(true) {
        Instantiate(baseball);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    }
}
```

Which can then be started with `StartCoroutine()` and terminated in one of three ways:

- internally by breaking out of the while loop with `break` (the function would then have no more lines to execute and exit)
- internally by `yield break`
- externally by calling `StopCoroutine()` on a reference to the coroutine

Comment: How can I use coroutine with prefab? When I want to update the code, it gives an error: `The type UnityEngine.GameObject[] cannot be used as type parameter T in the generic type or method UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate<T>(T). There is no implicit reference conversion from UnityEngine.GameObject[] to UnityEngine.O` @Draco18s

Comment: Prefabs have nothing to do with your problem, but rather that you're trying to pass *an array* to a function that does not take an array.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to the other answers: Just use a countdown. This sometimes gives you more control

```c#
// Set your offset here (in seconds)
float timeoutDuration = 2;

float timeout = 2;

void Update()
{
    if(timeout > 0)
    {
        // Reduces the timeout by the time passed since the last frame
        timeout -= Time.deltaTime;

        // return to not execute any code after that
        return;
    }

    // this is reached when timeout gets <= 0

    // Spawn object once
    Spawn();

    // Reset timer
    timeout = timeoutDuration;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I still can't achieve the expected result: https://i.imgur.com/c2TA5ZF.gif 
It's really hard to understand the issue for me.

Comment: I don't really get what you are doing or trying to archive to be honest. I wouldn't put this update function in the ball itself but on a seperated static gameoject. Right now it seems to be exponential because: you spawn a new ball every 2 seconds BUT: this newly spawned ball as well spawns a new ball every 2 seconds => after 2 seconds you have 2 balls, after 4 seconds both spawn a new ball => 4 balls; again after 2 seconds every of those spawn a new ball => 8 balls ....

Answer (score 0):

I updated my script by considering your feedbacks and it works like a charm. Thanks to all!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Threading;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {
    public float RotateSpeed = 45; //The ball rotates around its own axis
    public float BallSpeed = 0.2f; 

    public GameObject BaseBall;
    public Transform BallLocation;

    public Rigidbody2D Ball2D;

    void Start() {
        Ball2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); //Get component attached to gameobject
        InvokeRepeating("Spawn", 5.0f, 150f);
    }       

    void FixedUpdate() {
        Ball2D.MoveRotation(Ball2D.rotation + RotateSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime); //The ball rotates around its own axis
        Ball2D.AddForce(Vector2.left * BallSpeed);
    }

    public void Spawn () 
    {
        Instantiate (BaseBall, BallLocation.position, BallLocation.rotation);
    }
}
```